# How to repeat automatically character n times in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I need to repeat a lot of characteres n times using Notepad++.

I know that VI editor has the command to do it. Notepad++ has this command too?

Thanks!

Comment: Type it and hold the key. If you need a more precise answer, please precise the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could record a macro.  Then click Run a Macro Multiple times and run it 10 times.

Comment: Is it really more efficient than type ten times the same character?

Comment: I guess.  You could also record the macro as the 10 strokes and set it to a shortcut key.  It is more accurate.